# How could this query be improved?

Tags: sql, oracle

The following query works, but is not particularly fast:

```
select distinct controlid, (
                select max(Orderno) From my_table
                Where ControlID = #param1#
                    and a = 3 and b = 13 and c = 0 and d = 0
            ) colA, (
                Select max(Orderno) From my_table
                Where ControlID = #param1#
                    and a = 2
            ) colB, (
                Select max(Orderno) From my_table
                Where ControlID = #param1# 
                    and a = 1 and b = 14 and e = 1
            ) colC, (
                Select max(Orderno) From my_table
                Where ControlID = #param1# 
                    and a = 3 and b = 13 and e = 1 and c = 0 and d = 0
            ) colD, (
                Select a From my_table
                Where ControlID = #param1#
                    and Orderno = #param2#  
            ) colE
            from my_table
            where controlid = #param1#
```

The table being queried has over 300K rows, and the count of rows for a particular controlid (before the distinct clause) varies from 1 to 61. The profiler says the response time is 234/42 msecs. There are no indexes on the table.

Obviously, the lack of indexes is a problem, but beyond that, can anyone recommend a more efficient way of writing this query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use an aggregate instead of subqueries:

```
select distinct controlid, 
  max (case when a=3 and b=13 and c=0 and d= 0 then OrderNo end) as colA,
  max (case when a=2                           then OrderNo end) as colB,
  max (case when a=1 and b=14 and e=1          then OrderNo end) as colC,
  max (case when a=3 and b=13 and e=1 and c=0 and d=0 then OrderNo end) as colD,
  max (case when OrderNo=#param2# then a end) as colE
from my_table
where controlid = #param1#
group by controlid
```

I don't know which RDBMS you use, so the `case when` construct might have to be modified to your local dialect. This one should be valid for MSSQL

UPDATE: My glasses don't work properly and so I did not notice the ORACLE tag. Embarassing...

Comment: Probably oracle, due to the tag..?

Comment: To keep the same result for when the subqueries don't find anything, the else clause should be null above. Also the default value for a case expression is null so `else null` is unneeded, but sometimes useful to show intent.

Comment: Thanks to both you and Justin below - you beat him by two minutes so you get the prize. Justin's answer is slightly better in that the distinct turns out to be unnecessary. As an aside, we went ahead and added indexes to the table and the performance seems to be fairly equivalent between the original and the modified queries, but I'm filing this tip away for later use. Thanks again!

Comment: Even the `group by` is not necessary as `controlID` could be replaced by `#param1#`. Thanks for the prize ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to avoid hitting the table multiple times and do a single table scan

```
SELECT controlID,
       MAX( CASE WHEN a = 3
                  AND b = 13
                  AND c = 0 
                  AND d = 0
                 THEN orderNo
                 ELSE NULL
              END) colA,
       MAX( CASE WHEN a = 2
                 THEN orderNo
                 ELSE NULL
              END) colB,
       MAX( CASE WHEN a = 1
                  AND b = 14
                  AND e = 1
                 THEN orderNo
                 ELSE NULL
              END) colC,
       MAX( CASE WHEN a = 3
                  AND b = 13
                  AND e = 1
                  AND c = 0
                  AND d = 0
                 THEN orderNo
                 ELSE NULL
              END) colD,
       MAX( CASE WHEN orderNo = #param2#
                 THEN a
                 ELSE NULL
              END) colE
  FROM my_table
 WHERE controlId = #param1#
 GROUP BY controlID
```

Of course, it may well end up being more efficient to have appropriate indexes on the table and do multiple index scans.  Without knowing your data, it's hard to know.