# Retrieve a table to tallied numbers, best way

Tags: plsql, count

I have query that runs as part of a function which produces a one row table full of counts, and averages, and comma separated lists like this:

```
select
  (select 
    count(*)
    from vw_disp_details
    where round = 2013
    and rating = 1) applicants,
  (select 
    count(*)
    from vw_disp_details
    where round = 2013
    and rating = 1
    and applied != 'yes') s_applicants,
  (select 
    LISTAGG(discipline, ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY discipline) 
    from (select discipline,
          count(*) discipline_number 
          from vw_disp_details
          where round = 2013
          and rating = 1
          group by discipline)) disciplines,
  (select 
    LISTAGG(discipline_count, ',')
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY discipline)
    from (select discipline,
          count(*) discipline_count
          from vw_disp_details
          where round = 2013
          and rating = 1
          group by discipline)) disciplines_count,
  (select 
    round(avg(util.getawardstocols(application_id,'1','AWARD_NAME')), 2) 
    from vw_disp_details 
    where round = 2013
    and rating = 1) average_award_score,
  (select
    round(avg(age))
    from vw_disp_details
    where round = 2013
    and rating = 1) average_age
from dual;
```

Except that instead of 6 main sub-queries there are 23.

This returns something like this (if it were a CSV):

```
applicants | s_applicants | disciplines               | disciplines_count | average_award_score | average_age
107        | 67           | "speed,accuracy,strength" | 3                 | 97                  | 23
```

Now I am programmatically swapping out the "rating = 1" part of the where clauses for other expressions. They all work rather quickly except for the "rating = 1" one which takes about 90 seconds to run and that is because the rating column in the vw_disp_details view is itself compiled by a sub-query:

```
(SELECT score
FROM read r,
eval_criteria_lookup ecl
WHERE r.criteria_id        = ecl.criteria_id
AND r.application_id       = a.lgo_application_id
AND criteria_description   = 'Overall Score'
AND type                   = 'ABC'
) reader_rank
```

So when the function runs this extra query seems to slow everything down dramatically.

My question is, is there a better (more efficient) way to run a query like this that is basically just a series of counts and averages, and how can I refactor to optimize the speed so that the rating = 1 query doesn't take 90 seconds to run.

Comment: First you should try to combine the subqueries.  Use `CASE` to create conditional aggregates, similar to the solution to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15256082/409172).

Comment: I do use case to swap out "rating=1" with other conditions. That doesn't minimize the number of sub-queries that need to run.

Comment: I mean use `CASE` directly in your counts.  For example, something like: `select sum(case when round = 2013 and rating = 1 then 1 else 0 end) applicants, sum(case when round = 2013 and rating = 1 and applied != 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) s_applicants
...`.  You may not be able to combine all your subqueries, but you should be able to signifiacantly reduce the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue by doing two things: creating a new view that displayed only the results I needed, which gave me marginal gains in speed, and in that view moving the where clause of the sub-query that caused the lag into the where clause of the view and tacking on the result of the sub-query as column in the view. This still returns the same results thanks to the fact that there are always going to be records in the table the sub-query accessed for each row of the view query.

```
SELECT
  a.application_id,
  util.getstatus (a.application_id) status,
  (SELECT score
    FROM applicant_read ar,
    eval_criteria_lookup ecl
    WHERE ar.criteria_id        = ecl.criteria_id
    AND ar.application_id       = a.application_id
    AND criteria_description   = 'Overall Score'        //THESE TWO FIELDS
    AND type                   = 'ABC'                  //ARE CRITERIA_ID = 15
    ) score
  as.test_total test_total
FROM application a,
  applicant_scores as
WHERE a.application_id = as.application_id(+);
```

Became

```
SELECT
  a.application_id,
  util.getstatus (a.application_id) status,
  ar.score,
  as.test_total test_total
FROM application a,
  applicant_scores as,
  applicant_read ar
WHERE a.application_id = as.application_id(+)
AND ar.application_id  = a.application_id(+)
AND ar.criteria_id     = 15;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to MATERIALIZE the vw_disp_details VIEW. That would pre-calculate the value of the rating column. There are various options for how up-to-date a materialized view is kept, you would probably want to use the ON COMMIT clause so that vw_disp_details is always correct.

Have a look at the official documentation and see if that would work for you.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6002.htm

Comment: I'm trying this but I keep running into problems because some of the fields I want to compile into the materialized view from the original view use functions to get their value and this is throwing this error:

SQL Error: ORA-30357: this PL/SQL function cannot be supported for query rewrite
30357. 00000 -  "this PL/SQL function cannot be supported for query rewrite"
*Cause:    The statement referenced a PL/SQL function that is not marked DETERMINISTIC.

Answer (score 0):

Do all most of your queries in only one. Instead of doing:

```
select
  (select (count(*)                           from my_tab) as count_all,
  (select avg(age)                            from my_tab) as avg_age,
  (select avg(mypkg.get_award(application_id) from my_tab) as_avg-app_id 
from dual;
```

Just do:

```
select count(*), avg(age),avg(mypkg.get_award(application_id)) from my_tab;
```

And then, maybe you can do some union all for the other results. But this step all by itself should help.

Comment: I don't know how this would work since none of these sub-queries share the same where clause. Also I don't think having the 23 queries is problem. With other where clauses it runs in less than a second. The problem is that the rating field from the view is compiled from a sub-query that I think is delaying response. I think my only course of action is to a different narrower view.

Comment: Well depends: disciplines lies in disciplines_counts,averaged_award_score and averge_age are alike. In some cases you have the same `WHERE` + `GROUP BY`, plus you said you have 23 queries, maybe more of them could be factorized.